# How to assign conditional class to ul in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have tried as following code in wordpress  inside single.php file

```
 <?php echo $counter = $loop->post_count;?>
  <?php if($counter > 4){ ?>      
 <ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
 <?php } ?>
 <?php else { ?>
 <ul class="grid_12 relatedpost">
 <?php } ?>
  <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
<li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink()?>"><?php echo the_post_thumbnail();?></a></li>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
  </ul>
```

This doesn't work. Could anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine to me, but for what it's worth I would recommend something like this:

```
$classes = array('grid_12', 'relatedpost');

if ($loop->post_count > 4) {

    $classes[] = 'jcarousel-skin-tango';

}

printf('<ul id="mycarousel" class="%s">', implode(" ", $classes));
```